# Is there simple way (syntax) to write nested case statement in order to understand it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there particular syntax for writing nested case statement?
I have a stored procedure that I need to figure out what is going on and thought maybe there is an easier way to understand nested case statement?

```
SELECT
       CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], '') <> '' AND NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.EndorsementNumber = NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.EndorsementNumber
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
                        WHEN 'ADD' THEN 'Add'
                        WHEN 'DELETED' THEN 'Delete'
                        WHEN 'CHANGED' THEN 'Change'
                        WHEN 'New Quote' THEN 'Add'
                    ELSE 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
                            THEN 'Add'
                            ELSE 
                                CASE WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 
                                THEN 'Delete' 
                                ELSE 'No Change' 
                            END
                     END
                 END
                 ELSE 
                 CASE WHEN tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
                 THEN 'Add'
                 ELSE 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 
                        THEN 'Delete' 
                        ELSE 'No Change' 
                    END
                  END
               END as TransactionName


        FROM
```

Comment: What would you consider "easier"? You could unnest the nested `CASE` expression but that would make the conditional expression of the parent expression more complex and adds more branches to the parent expression. If that is in any way easier? I don't know... as well as I currently not know whether to vote as "primarily opinion based" on this...

Comment: You might find breaking out the logic into separate CVEs may help. They often help me clarify the logic by processing it one layer at a time. I know inline functions would be less performant but they would break down visually and allow for keeping the larger logic more clear. Also, the simplest case is an IIF(), but visually it may be more confusing.

Comment: I have found that if I properly format Nested Case Statements they are much easier to read and understand. @Oleg

Comment: I agree, that's what I am trying to figure out what would be proper format for such statements?

Comment: "proper format" and "easier" are very much opinion based. Personally I would probably nest the logic in a few layers. Have an inner subselect that does some transformation so you can actually see the result, then have an outer select that applies some more. Then it's a bit easier to debug but far more verbose. It also depends on the actual logic applied

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd write it like this:

```
select
    case
    when isNull(NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], '') <> ''
            and NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.EndorsementNumber
              = NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.EndorsementNumber
    then
        case NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
        when 'ADD'          then 'Add'
        when 'DELETED'      then 'Delete'
        when 'CHANGED'      then 'Change'
        when 'New Quote'    then 'Add'
        else
            case
            when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is null
                or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
            then 'Add'
            else
                case
                when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12
                then 'Delete'
                else 'No Change'
                end
            end
        end
    else
        case
        when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is null
            or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
        then 'Add'
        else
            case
            when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12
            then 'Delete'
            else 'No Change'
            end
        end
    end as TransactionName
from ...
```

But I'd remove some case's:

```
select
    case
    when isNull(NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], '')
                in ('ADD','DELETE','CHANGED','New Quote')
            and NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.EndorsementNumber
              = NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.EndorsementNumber
    then
        case NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
        when 'ADD'          then 'Add'
        when 'DELETED'      then 'Delete'
        when 'CHANGED'      then 'Change'
        when 'New Quote'    then 'Add'
        end
    else
        case
        when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is null
            or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
        then 'Add'
        else
            case
            when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12
            then 'Delete'
            else 'No Change'
            end
        end
    end as TransactionName
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This variation flattens the `CASE WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12` logic into the surrounding `case` for both occurrences since there is no benefit in nesting the *searched case* expressions:

```
case
  when IsNull( NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], '' ) <> '' and
    NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.EndorsementNumber = NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.EndorsementNumber
    then
      case NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
        when 'ADD'       then 'Add'
        when 'DELETED'   then 'Delete'
        when 'CHANGED'   then 'Change'
        when 'New Quote' then 'Add'
        else
          case
            when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is NULL or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
              then 'Add'
            when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 then 'Delete'
            else 'No Change' 
            end
        end
  else
    case
      when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is NULL or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
        then 'Add'
      when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 then 'Delete' 
      else 'No Change' 
      end
    end as TransactionName
```

If `NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]` can only have the values listed (`'ADD'`, `'DELETED'`, `'CHANGED'` and `'New Quote'`) then any other value would result in a `NULL` result in the absence of an `else` clause. You can use that with `coalesce` to collapse the large block of repeating code:

```
Coalesce(
  case
    when IsNull( NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], '' ) <> '' and
      NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.EndorsementNumber = NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.EndorsementNumber
      then
        case NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
          when 'ADD'       then 'Add'
          when 'DELETED'   then 'Delete'
          when 'CHANGED'   then 'Change'
          when 'New Quote' then 'Add'
          end,
  case
    when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid is NULL or NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate'
      then 'Add'
    when tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 then 'Delete' 
    else 'No Change' 
    end ) as TransactionName
```

Answer (score 0):

When table or column names make things get very horizontal, I use aliases.  So in your 'from' and 'join' statements, I would alias NetRate_Quote_insur_quote to something like 'nQuote', and 'NetRate_Quote_insur_quote_locat' to something like 'loc'.

Besides that, for things that take more than one line, I like the colName = xyz syntax.

Also I like 'case' lined up with the 'when', 'else', and 'end' statements, and if feasible, 'then' statements not in line with these rest.

So it would look like this:

```
select  TransactionName = 
            CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(loc.[Transaction], '') <> '' AND loc.EndorsementNumber = nQuote.EndorsementNumber THEN 
                CASE loc.[Transaction]
                WHEN 'ADD' THEN 'Add'
                WHEN 'DELETED' THEN 'Delete'
                WHEN 'CHANGED' THEN 'Change'
                WHEN 'New Quote' THEN 'Add'
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR nQuote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate' THEN 'Add'
                    ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 THEN 'Delete' 
                        ELSE 'No Change' 
                        END
                    END
                END
            ELSE 
                CASE 
                WHEN tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR nQuote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate' THEN 'Add'
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 THEN 'Delete' 
                    ELSE 'No Change' 
                    END
                END
            END
```

Also, I find often it is helpful to put repeating case logic into cross apply statements.  So if, after your join statements, you can add something like:

```
cross apply (select 
    endorsed = 
        case 
        when ISNULL(loc.[Transaction], '') <> '' AND loc.EndorsementNumber = nQuote.EndorsementNumber then 1
        else 0 
        end,
    nullOrReinstate = 
        case 
        when tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR nQuote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate' then 1
        else 0
        end
) ap
```

then you can use those columns in your logic.  In the end, if I didn't make a mistake, I believe your case statement can be unnested to look like this:

```
select  TransactionName = 
            CASE 
            WHEN endorsed = 1 and loc.[Transaction] in ('add', 'deleted', 'changed') then loc.[transaction]
            WHEN endorsed = 1 and loc.[transaction] = 'New Quote' THEN 'Add'
            WHEN endorsed = 1 and nullOrReinstate = 1 THEN 'Add'
            WHEN endorsed = 1 and tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 THEN 'Delete' 
            WHEN nullOrReinstate = 1 THEN 'Add'
            WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 THEN 'Delete' 
            ELSE 'No Change' 
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that most of this is unnecessary. I resolved it out and think that the outer case is not required because you are checking for transaction being not empty, then in a nested check testing for its values. If you exclude this part then the two outer case conditions are the same, which means the whole nesting can be removed. I'm pretty sure it evaluates to the below.

In general you have a lot of `ELSE CASE xxx` clauses where the second case could simply be added as more WHEN clauses to the original case, particularly if you dont use the `CASE value` and replace it with the `CASE WHEN value=` syntax.

This is what I think it all resolves to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]='ADD' THEN 'Add'
    WHEN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]='DELETED' THEN 'Delete'
    WHEN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]='CHANGED' THEN 'Change'
    WHEN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]='New Quote' THEN 'Add'
    WHEN tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGuid IS NULL OR NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote.TypeofBusiness = 'Reinstate' THEN 'Add'
    WHEN tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = 12 THEN 'Delete' 
    ELSE 'No Change' 
END as TransactionName
```

Answer (score -1):

I can save you few lines

```
    case NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction]
    when 'ADD'          then 'Add'
    when 'DELETED'      then 'Delete'
    when 'CHANGED'      then 'Change'
```

Can become

```
    case when NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction] in ('ADD', 'DELETED', 'CHANGED') then LEFT(NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat.[Transaction], 6)
```

Comment: Oh, god no.  Don't do that.  It may seem convenient in this case because the letters match up.  But that's so easily broken.  And can so easily lead to branched logic to handle any cases where the letters don't match nicely.

Comment: In the original only the first letter is a capital. In what you suggest all are capitals (or in whatever casing they were with certain collations). It's therefore not equivalent.